# I have a Microsoft UWP application that I would like to convert to MAUI

Tags: uwp

Project Reunion allows the creation of new UWP applications using WinUI3, but I am wondering what my options are for an existing UWP application. I would like to avoid distributing the app through the Microsoft Store and to use the more standard Xamarin Forms version of Xaml. Is there a way to convert an existing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To distribute UWP app without Microsoft Store, right click project in the Solution Explorer and generate MSIX package. You'll need code signing certificate for this option.
2. Xamarin uses nonstandard dialect of XAML incompatible with WPF, Silverlight and UWP. Before Microsoft bought this project, it was private company and for legal reasons they invented their own dialect. To make WPF or UWP app crossplatform, you'll have to either rewrite all your XAML to Xamarin / MAUI, or try Uno, but it is a project of independent company, not Microsoft.

Comment: I try UNO and didn't really understand it's concept, is there any easy guide so instead of rewriting everything we can do some quick copy paste of code or search replace to make it working with Xamarin or Maui